# express.js - using stylus as middleware or build it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stylus

I want to use **Stylus** (http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/) preprocessor in my *express.js* application.

What is the best practice for using it (or simply share your experience) -

- build stylus files with *grunt.js* or smth similar tool before starting application?
- or using it as middleware `app.use(stylus.middleware...)` - the main thing here is - how that deals with apps performance (because as I see this middleware runs on every request while writing css files)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using middleware the first time and write the result to file, which as the cache, would serve the next request. Just like "coffee-middleware" and "less-middleware".